# Regular expression related to credit card

Tags: vbscript

I would like to validate master card for New series The BIN range `(222100-272099)`. currently I have Regular expression for existing mastercard series...`5[1-5][0-9]{14}`

Comment: Edit you question and post the vbscript code !

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. Please try writing the code yourself. You should identify what you have done so far and post any relevant code. As an established user, you should be familiar with: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); please consider editing your question accordingly.

Comment: it's a good range to use math instead of regular expressions btw. `isValidMasterCard = (Left(num, 2) >= 51 And Left(num, 2) <= 55) Or (Left(num, 6) >= 222100 And Left(num, 6) <= 272099)`

Comment: We have currently regular expression for all other credit cards.. and specifications are written to add Regular expression to new series so it has to be with regular expression... Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit :*** based on the comment of ***Kul-Tigin***

When working with numbers this may be easier :

```
Title = "Valid card number or not"
Do 
    CardNumber = InputBox("Please type your card number ",Title,"222100")
    If IsValidcard(CardNumber) = True Then
        MsgBox CardNumber & " The Card number is valid !",64,Title
    Else
        MsgBox CardNumber & " The Card number is not valid !",16,Title
    End if
Loop Until CardNumber = ""
'**********************************************************************
Function IsValidCard(Num)
    IsValidCard = False
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "^\d{6}$"
    If regEx.Test(Num) then
        x = CDbl(num)
        if x >= 222100 AND x <= 272099 Then
            IsValidCard = True
        Else
            'not in range
        End If
    Else
        'not 6 digits
    end if
End Function
'**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks It helps me start on proper route.

Comment: downvote is mine. first, it must start with `^`, otherwise it works like `contains`. but more importantly, the pattern is insufficient. it won't match with `260271` for example, which is a number in the valid range.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin i edit my answer so check it now !

Comment: using math is also [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846137/regular-expression-related-to-credit-card/36850700#comment61263017_36846137) but OP wants a regex solution  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ .  I'd prefer this too btw.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin so in this case i still deserve your downvote or not ?  :)